# How does work schedule for Job and commands?

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, schedule, job-scheduling

How does work schedule in this situation? I have a table - tasks. `foreach` runs over the collection and launches the schedule with a job or command `$schedule->job(new Auto('Audio', 2001))->cron($expression)`. At first it runs with these parameters `Audio,2001 - every 3 minutes` . After it will run with parameters `BMW, 2013 - every 4 minutes` Will it work in the same time? What can I do that it will work synchronized?

```
$tasks = Task::all();
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            $schedule->job(new AutoJob($task->car->mark, $task->car->year))->cron($task->expression);
        }
```

I needn't in some Jobs, schedules and etc. I need in only in one schedule BUT dynamic. I want to pass different parameters to schedule and it has to work, BUT it does not have to replace, it has to add new one. Does it possible?

Comment: So, if you want to run a task and when it finished run another one (depends on the previous one to finish first to run), you can use [Task Hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#task-hooks). If this is not what you are looking for, can you share code and explain a little more ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti It does not have to finish, it has to run and first with parameres Audi every 3 minutes and second with another parameteres. BUT the first has to work too, it does not have to finish when the second will start running. They have to work synchronizely.

Comment: I am confused, sorry. So you want to run the first job with `Audio, 2001`, after 4 minutes of exactly running that job with those parameters, you want to run it again but with `BMW, 2013`, after 2 minutes of this job been run, you will run `Audio, 2001` again (because it has already pass 3 minutes again), and so on. Do you want to do that ? If you do, what is the problem of scheduling each one ? Show us the code that is doing so.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have added

Comment: If you schedule `Audio, 2001` and then `BMW, 2013`, is the second one replacing the first one ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, I have meant it. And this is my question

Comment: I am looking at the source code and I see no code that is allowing a "replace" because it is just dispatching a Job either instantly or after a time (if it implements `ShouldQueue`). So how do you know the job is being replaced and not run ? Do you have any error ? How do you know each job is run when run ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it just does not run in common, I tried to do php artisan schedule:run. And it did not have any errors, but I added logs in AutoJob ```         Log::info('Test AutoJob');
``` and there are not any texts.

Comment: Have you run `php artisan queue:work` or `php artisan queue:listen` ? You are dispatching jobs to the queue, that is why you are not getting any executed.

Comment: @matiaslauriti ok, thank you